# Java Math.acos() return values

Tags: java

So I was writing a program to do some calculation and I noticed I wasn't getting the results I expected.

I am using the Math.acos() and Math.sqrt() functions, and when I expect to get a zero answer, I am getting incredibly small almost zero answers.

```
> System.out.println(Math.acos(27441738 / (Math.sqrt(27441738)*Math.sqrt(27441738))));
1.4901161193847656E-8
```

This, typically, should print out 0.0.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: `1.4901161193847656E-8` is _almost_ 0. floating point numbers cannot represent these values exactly. Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: is 1.5e-8 not close enough?

Comment: Well, the issue was that I was comparing two quantities and determining their distance from each other in radians, so when I am comparing two identical quantities I would prefer it to display that their distance is 0.  I'll just have it round.

Comment: For comparison see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434657/java-double-value-comparison

Comment: You have to compare floating point values by using an epsilon value; there's no `= 0` checking.

Comment: The "What every computer scientist" article is great, but a bit much for first-timers I think. http://floating-point-gui.de is a gentler introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule to narrow down the error in expressions that involve floating point operations.

For this particular case, you can make use of [fraction rationalization](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/rational-expressions/rational_expressions/v/rationalizing-denominators-of-expressions) to  drastically mitigate the error:

```
                                              -------------
        x        x     1     x     1    √x    |  x    √x  |
 1 = -------- = --- * --- = --- * --- * --- = | --- * --- |  
     √x * √x    √x     √x   √x    √x    √x    | √x     x  |
                                              -------------
```

Evaluating the new expression (using `bsh`):

```
System.out.println( Math.acos( (27441738 / Math.sqrt(27441738)) * (Math.sqrt(27441738) / 27441738) ) );
```

Prints:

```
0.0
```

A thing about the suggested reading, as others have pointed out a good starting point to get information about FP is "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)" a treatise of floating point operations in detail, although I prefer [Computer Representation of Numbers and Computer Arithmetic](https://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsl.cs.vt.edu%2FDeposit%2Fcomp_arithm.pdf&ei=wz4qUv_ZF4Xy8ASFwoCwDw&usg=AFQjCNEsbUx8YJOkqaymYKxTNrpSPkq7fQ&sig2=OTbCLKHwECPhq713Dy3dow&bvm=bv.51773540,d.eWU&cad=rja), which is simpler and more pedagogical, it even starts with a toy fp system that introduce you to the complex concepts of floating point operations.