# Compare first two decimal points

Tags: java, split, decimal

Suppose if I have 3.13 and 4.13, I want to be able to check whether .13 from 3.13 and .13 from 4.13.

I tried many things:

1) converting the two decimals to Strings and trying to split them up by ".", but I couldnt get that to work

2) `a = 3.14;
a = a - Math.floor(a);` to try to get the decimal alone but i end up getting 0.1400000001

Comment: _converting the two decimals to Strings and trying to split them up by ".", but I couldnt get that to work_ **:** `split` uses a regex, so you have to escape the dot. `string.split(".")` should become `string.split("\\.")`, try it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

> converting the two decimals to Strings and trying to split them up by ".", but I couldnt get that to work

`split` uses a regex, so you have to escape the dot.

```
string.split(".")
```

should become

```
string.split("\\.")
```

With this you should be able to split the string properly and do your comparisons

---

By the way, i would use [Reimenus solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826690/compare-first-two-decimal-points#answer-18826849), when you have numbers it's always better to use math if you can. Use strings **only if you really need them.**

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the fractional part for comparison instead

```
double value1 = 3.13;
double value2 = 4.13;
double fractional1 = value1 - (long)value1;
double fractional2 = value2 - (long)value2;
System.out.println(Double.compare(fractional1, fractional2));
```

Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) too see
why you're seeing additional digits after your own numerical operation

Comment: +1! Using String operations for numbers is something I don't like. When playing with numbers, always do the MATH!

Answer (score 0):

your second method is actually correct. when comparing double  values, you have to include a range.. [Java: Double Value Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434657/java-double-value-comparison) (refer this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        float v1 = 3.13f,v2 = 4.13f;
        //Converting float value into String array
        String split1[]=Float.toString(v1).split("\\.");
        String split2[]=Float.toString(v2).split("\\.");

        //Comparing two strings
        if(split1[1].equals(split2[1]))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } 
    }
}
```