# Data validation to an throw exception

Tags: java, validation, double, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to read in a figure for a brokers earnings for quarter one of the year.I want  to ensure that 0 or less can not be entered but when I enter 0 it just takes it in anyway and does not throw the exception? 
What am I doing wrong?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public void setQuarter1(double newQuarter1)
 {
   if ( newQuarter1 > 0)
     quarter1 = newQuarter1;
   else
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("new quarter must be > 0.0");
 }
```

Ok heres my whole assignment code

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Broker {

//(a) declare instance variables

private String department, firstName, lastName;
private double quarter1, quarter2, quarter3, quarter4;




//(b) Access methods for instance variables

public void setDepartmentName(String newName)
{
    department=newName;
}


public String getDepartment ()
{
    return department;
}

//set and get methods for first name

public void setFirstName (String newFirstName)
{
    firstName=newFirstName;
}


public String getFirstName ()
{
    return firstName;
}

//set and get methods for last name

public void setLastName(String newLastName)
{
    lastName=newLastName;
}

public String getLastName ()
{
    return lastName;
}

//set and get methods for Quarter 1

public void setQuarter1(double newQuarter1)
{

    if ( newQuarter1 > 0)
          quarter1 = newQuarter1;
        else
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "new quarter  must be > 0.0");


}


public double getQuarter1()
{
    return quarter1;
}

//set and get methods for Quarter 2

public void setQuarter2(double newQuarter2)
{
    quarter2 = newQuarter2;
}

public double getQuarter2 ()
{
    return quarter2;
}

//set and get methods for Quarter 3

public void setQuarter3(double newQuarter3)
{
    quarter2 = newQuarter3;
}

public double getQuarter3 ()
{
    return quarter3;
}



//set and get methods for Quarter 4

public void setQuarter4(double newQuarter4)
{
    quarter4 = newQuarter4;
}

public double getQuarter4 ()
{
    return quarter4;
}

//(c) class variable annualbrokerage total and two access methods

private static double brokerageTotal;


public void setbrokerageTotal(double newBrokerageTotal)
{
    newBrokerageTotal=brokerageTotal;
}


//(c) constructor to initialise instance variables department,firstname and lastname

public Broker (String dept, String first, String last )
{
    department = dept;
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;

}



// (d) constructor to initialise all instance variables from (a)

public Broker (String dept, String first, String last,double q1,double q2,double q3,double q4 )
{
    department = dept;
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    quarter1 = q1;
    quarter2 = q2;
    quarter3 = q3;
    quarter4 = q4;


}


// (e) no-argument constructor to initialise default broker instance

public Broker ()
{
    department = null;
    firstName = null;
    lastName = null;
    quarter1 = 0;
    quarter2 = 0;
    quarter3 = 0;
    quarter4 = 0;
}


//(f)   Method to read in quarters from user

public void readInQuarters ()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


     System.out.println("Please enter Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 figures for broker:");






        quarter1 = input.nextInt();
        quarter2 = input.nextInt();
        quarter3 = input.nextInt();
        quarter4 = input.nextInt();



 }  //end of read in quarters method



 // (g) getBrokerTotal Method to return total trades for 4 quarters


public double getBrokerTotal()

 {

     //code to calculate broker quarterly totals

     double brokerTotal = quarter1 + quarter2 + quarter3 + quarter4;

     return brokerTotal;
 }   //end of getBrokerTotal method


//(e)  getBonus method to calculate brokers bonus

public double getBonus()
 {

   double bonusRate=0;
   double bonus=0;


    //bonus rate depending on department rate

   if("Dublin"==department)
          bonusRate=.12;
   else if("London"==department)
          bonusRate=.15;
   else
      bonusRate=.10;

     bonus = (quarter1 + quarter2 + quarter3 + quarter4)*(bonusRate);
        return bonus;
  }


   //(i) to string method for broker class

   public String toString()
     {
      return String.format("  Name: "+ getFirstName()+"\n  Surname: "+getLastName()+"\n  Department: "+getDepartment()+"\n  Total: "+getBrokerTotal()+"\n  Bonus: "+getBonus()+"\n\n");
     }//end of toString method





    //(i) Static methods to read in broker array and output quarterly totals

     //Quarter1 totals method
    public static double getQuarter1Total (Broker[]brokerQuarter1Array)

         {
            double quarter1Total = brokerQuarter1Array[0].getQuarter1()+ brokerQuarter1Array[1].getQuarter1()+ brokerQuarter1Array[2].getQuarter1()+ brokerQuarter1Array[3].getQuarter1()
                                   + brokerQuarter1Array[4].getQuarter1() + brokerQuarter1Array[5].getQuarter1();

                                   return quarter1Total;
         }


     //Quarter2 totals method
    public static double getQuarter2Total (Broker[]brokerQuarter2Array)

        {
            double quarter2Total = brokerQuarter2Array[0].getQuarter2()+ brokerQuarter2Array[1].getQuarter2()+ brokerQuarter2Array[2].getQuarter2()+ brokerQuarter2Array[3].getQuarter2()
                                   + brokerQuarter2Array[4].getQuarter2() + brokerQuarter2Array[5].getQuarter2();

                                   return quarter2Total;
        }


     //Quarter3 totals method
    public static double getQuarter3Total (Broker[]brokerQuarter3Array)

    {
        double quarter3Total = brokerQuarter3Array[0].getQuarter3()+ brokerQuarter3Array[1].getQuarter3()+ brokerQuarter3Array[2].getQuarter3()+ brokerQuarter3Array[3].getQuarter3()
                               + brokerQuarter3Array[4].getQuarter3() + brokerQuarter3Array[5].getQuarter3();

                               return quarter3Total;
    }


     //Quarter4 totals method
    public static double getQuarter4Total (Broker[]brokerQuarter4Array)

        {
            double quarter4Total = brokerQuarter4Array[0].getQuarter4()+ brokerQuarter4Array[1].getQuarter4()+ brokerQuarter4Array[2].getQuarter4()+ brokerQuarter4Array[3].getQuarter4()
                                   + brokerQuarter4Array[4].getQuarter4() + brokerQuarter4Array[5].getQuarter4();

                                   return quarter4Total;
    }




   // Static method to calculate total brokerage totals for all brokers

public static void setBrokerageTotal (Broker[] brokerTotalsArray)

            {
             double annualBrokerageTotal= brokerTotalsArray[0].getBrokerTotal() + brokerTotalsArray[1].getBrokerTotal()

             + brokerTotalsArray[2].getBrokerTotal() + brokerTotalsArray[3].getBrokerTotal() + brokerTotalsArray[4].getBrokerTotal() + brokerTotalsArray[5].getBrokerTotal();

             }


 // Static method to get the total bonuses for all brokers cobined

  public static double getBrokerageBonus (Broker [] brokerageBonusTotalArray)

            {
             double totalBrokerageBonus  = brokerageBonusTotalArray[0].getBonus()+ brokerageBonusTotalArray[1].getBonus()+ brokerageBonusTotalArray[2].getBonus()+ brokerageBonusTotalArray[3].getBonus()
             + brokerageBonusTotalArray[4].getBonus() + brokerageBonusTotalArray[5].getBonus();

                return totalBrokerageBonus;
    }




public static void main(String[]args)

{

    //Part-B


    ///(a) create broker1 with the no argument constructor

    Broker broker1=new Broker();

    broker1.setDepartmentName("Dublin");
    broker1.setFirstName("John");
    broker1.setLastName("Wall");
    broker1.setQuarter1(12);
    broker1.setQuarter2(24);
    broker1.setQuarter3(26);
    broker1.setQuarter4(17);

    System.out.print(broker1);



//(b) create broker2

    Broker broker2 = new Broker("London","Sarah","May");
    broker2.setQuarter1(8);
    broker2.setQuarter2(11);
    broker2.setQuarter3(7);
    broker2.setQuarter4(9);

    System.out.print(broker2);


//(c) create broker3

     Broker broker3 = new Broker("London","Ruth","Lavin");
     //call read in quarters method
     broker3.readInQuarters();

   System.out.print(broker3);




//(d) create broker4,broker5,broker6
     Broker broker4=new Broker("Dublin","Conor","Smith",21,23,26,31);
     Broker broker5=new Broker("Paris","Jerome","Duignan",14,14,17,18);
     Broker broker6=new Broker("Paris","Patick","Bateman",23,24,26,35);


//(e)  Create broker array

     Broker[] brokers;
     brokers=new Broker [6];

     brokers[0]=broker1;brokers[1]=broker2;brokers[2]=broker3;brokers[3]=broker4;brokers[4]=broker5;brokers[5]=broker6;



//(f)  Output second table
      String[] headings ={"Dept","Firstname","Surname","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Total","Bonus"};


        //loop to print the headings
     for (int i = 0; i < headings.length; i++)

       {
         System.out.print(headings[i]+"     ");
       }


       //print a space under the headings
          System.out.println(" \n");


       //loop to print the main table plus format specifiers to align the text


     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {

          System.out.printf("%-7s  %-13s %-11s %-6s %-6s %-6s %-6s %-10s %.1f \n\n",brokers[i].getDepartment(), brokers[i].getFirstName(),brokers[i].getLastName(),brokers[i].getQuarter1(),brokers[i].getQuarter2(),brokers[i].getQuarter3(),brokers[i].getQuarter4(),brokers[i].getBrokerTotal(),brokers[i].getBonus());
       }
    //  console printout for quarterly totals

 System.out.printf("%33s \n","Quarterly ");
 System.out.printf("%29  %9s  %6s %6s %6s %6s  \n","Total ",getQuarter1Total(brokers),getQuarter2Total(brokers),getQuarter3Total(brokers),getQuarter4Total(brokers),getBrokerageBonus(brokers));

}    //end of method main


}    //end of class broker
```

er

Comment: Are you sure you are entering 0? Try to print `newQuarter1` before the condition.

Comment: You will need to debug. Here are some ideas for what might be wrong, each of which you should test: Not calling this method. Calling it with a different value. Silently catching the exception before it gets to the code intended to handle it.

Comment: if newquarter1 is 0.0 or 0 then you will get exception. Share your complete code here.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434657/java-double-value-comparison

Comment: @Xiezi Zero is one of the values that is exactly representable in double, so rounding should not be an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using your setters. The problem is here

```
public void readInQuarters () {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 figures for broker:");
  quarter1 = input.nextInt(); // <-- Use your setters!
  quarter2 = input.nextInt();
  quarter3 = input.nextInt();
  quarter4 = input.nextInt();

  // should be,
  setQuarter1(input.nextInt()); // and so on... although I will point out, you should
                                // be reading double(s) apparently.
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I see it now and Thanks for pointing out I should have doubles aswell.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend I have give a suggestion which is am also use in our project
call this method before submitting the value. And if return true then update data other wise show mgs in validate method of where from call update

```
boolean validate() {

int c = Integer.parseInt(txtFieldSetupTopElevation.getText().toString().trim());

if (c <= 0) {
// Here use code for show msg error or information
// return true if value is greater than 0 other wise return else
return false;
     }
}
```

Sandeep